# Check that request from app to wiremock was compressed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, wiremock

Is there easy way to check in test that request from app* under test to wiremock was compressed? I wrote some code that should gzip my requests, but I want to verify it with wiremock. I can check that "content-encodig: gzip" is set which I set by myself, but I also want to check that body is gzipped (i've done it also). Boolean answer that it was, or not gzipped is enough for me.

*) spring boot app